# Time complexity of derivation, gradient,differential, jacobian matrix

Tags: complexity

what is the time complexity of gradient $\nabla_{f}$ using the $\mathcal O$-notation?
what is the time complexity of jacobian matrix using the $\mathcal O$-notation?
who knows some references to introduce the time complexity of gradient?
I make reply to reviewers for computational complexity of gradient and matrix operations. I need some references to cite.

Comment: For the numerical calculation of a 1D derivative at a single point, you require at least two points (left aside methods like the complex step-derivative). So that's O(1). You can carry that forward to higher dimensions and then to vectors and matrices.

Comment: What algorithms are you using to compute your derivatives?  Finite differencing?  Automatic Differentiation (in forward or reverse mode)? How complicated is $f$?